# Apex REST end point Time out error

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I'm calling the Salesforce REST End point from Node.js and getting the error ESOCKETTIMEDOUT sometimes. Any thoughts?

Comment: This the problem at your Node.js server end. Or the authentication is not proper at Salesforce code. Please check any documentation of implementation if available.

Comment: Thanks, There shouldn't be any problem with authentication because I've exposed the REST End Point using Force.com Sites (I'm using my own signature to validate the request in SF).

Comment: Check your REST service from Postman or SoapUI to check if this issue is with Salesforce.

Comment: @SarojBera Thanks, I'm getting this error rarely and not always (let's say once in one day). So just need to make sure is there anything that needs to be done on the Salesforce side.

Comment: So curious to know - how much time will it take for salesforce to respond to a REST call? I didn't see any documentation for the same.